# Android Video Camera : still picture

Tags: android, video, camera

I use the camera intent to capture video. Here is the problem:
If I use this line of code, I can record video. But `onActivityResult` doesn't work.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.VIDEO_CAMERA");
```

If I use this line of code, after press the recording button, the camera is freezed, I mean, 
the picture is still.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
```

BTW, when I use `Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);` to capture a picture, it works fine.

The java file is as follows:

```
package com.camera.picture;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;
public class PictureCameraActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int IMAGE_CAPTURE = 0;
    private static final int VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;
    private Button startBtn;
    private Button videoBtn;
    private Uri imageUri;
    private Uri videoUri;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private VideoView videoView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. 
     *  sets the content and gets the references to 
     *  the basic widgets on the screen like
     *  {@code Button} or {@link ImageView}
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
        videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startCamera();
            }
        });

        videoBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.videoBtn);
        videoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startVideoCamera();
            }
        });
    }

    public void startCamera() {
        Log.d("ANDRO_CAMERA", "Starting camera on the phone...");
        String fileName = "testphoto.jpg";
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,
                "Image capture by camera");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Log.d("ANDROID_CAMERA","Picture taken!!!");
                imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == VIDEO_CAPTURE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d("ANDROID_CAMERA","Video taken!!!");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved to:\n" +
                        data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
            }
        }
    }

    private void startVideoCamera() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //create new Intent

        Log.d("ANDRO_CAMERA", "Starting camera on the phone...");
        String fileName = "testvideo.mp4";
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, fileName);
        values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DESCRIPTION,
                "Video captured by camera");
        values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
        videoUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.VIDEO_CAMERA");
        //Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

        // start the Video Capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    }

    private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        return mediaFile;
    }

    /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(){
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE to record Video .

```
Intent photoPickerIntent= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
              startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(photoPickerIntent,"Take Video"),TAKE_VIDEO);
```

And your OnActivityResult must be like this to Save Video in particular location :

```
if(requestCode==TAKE_VIDEO)
            {


                try
                {
                    Log.e("videopath","videopath");
                AssetFileDescriptor videoAsset = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(data.getData(), "r");
                FileInputStream fis = videoAsset.createInputStream();
                File root=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Directory");

                  if (!root.exists()) {
                      root.mkdirs();
                  }
                  File file;

                   file = new File(root,filename+".mp4" );

                 Uri uri=Uri.fromFile(file);
                 Item1.videopath=uri.getPath();

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    fos.write(buf, 0, len);
                }       
                fis.close();
                fos.close();


              } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I am a new come to Android. The App is designed to record video and transmit to a PC via network. Can you give me any guide or some articles I can refer to. @Abhi

Comment: What're the two lines of codes usde for?                    `Uri uri=Uri.fromFile(file);`
`Item1.videopath=uri.getPath();`@Abhi

Comment: it is get the path of the video stored in SD card... trasmit means you want to Upload it to server?

Comment: I want to transmit the video to PC while recording, i.e, real time recording video and transmit it. At the same time, the PC or server can play the video. It somehow likes  making Android phone as a surveillance camera while the PC as a screen.@Abhi